# Thumbnail grid with expanding preview navigation

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, grid-layout

I have implemented the grid into a [site](http://www.thebarnandpinncottage.co.uk/cottage) and it's all working great! I have added a previous and next button using the JavaScript file to append them but can't seem to get them to cycle previous and next.

I notice Google's image search you can use the arrow keys to cycle through them but would like to use these buttons to do it. I know you can target the name attribute and cycle through the images but in this particular grid there is only the `data-largesrc` which I can't seem to target (I can target the `img src` of the thumbs. The images are in `<li>` so maybe that could be targeted? Any ideas would be appreciated. The JavaScript file is a bit big...

```
    /*
* debouncedresize: special jQuery event that happens once after a window resize
*
* latest version and complete README available on Github:
* https://github.com/louisremi/jquery-smartresize/blob/master/jquery.debouncedresize.js
*
* Copyright 2011 @louis_remi
* Licensed under the MIT license.
*/
var $jevent = $j.event,
$jspecial,
resizeTimeout;

$jspecial = $jevent.special.debouncedresize = {
    setup: function() {
        $j( this ).on( "resize", $jspecial.handler );
    },
    teardown: function() {
        $j( this ).off( "resize", $jspecial.handler );
    },
    handler: function( event, execAsap ) {
        // Save the context
        var context = this,
            args = arguments,
            dispatch = function() {
                // set correct event type
                event.type = "debouncedresize";
                $jevent.dispatch.apply( context, args );
            };

        if ( resizeTimeout ) {
            clearTimeout( resizeTimeout );
        }

        execAsap ?
            dispatch() :
            resizeTimeout = setTimeout( dispatch, $jspecial.threshold );
    },
    threshold: 250
};

// ======================= imagesLoaded Plugin ===============================
// https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

// $j('#my-container').imagesLoaded(myFunction)
// execute a callback when all images have loaded.
// needed because .load() doesn't work on cached images

// callback function gets image collection as argument
//  this is the container

// original: MIT license. Paul Irish. 2010.
// contributors: Oren Solomianik, David DeSandro, Yiannis Chatzikonstantinou

// blank image data-uri bypasses webkit log warning (thx doug jones)
var BLANK = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==';

$j.fn.imagesLoaded = function( callback ) {
    var $jthis = this,
        deferred = $j.isFunction($j.Deferred) ? $j.Deferred() : 0,
        hasNotify = $j.isFunction(deferred.notify),
        $jimages = $jthis.find('img').add( $jthis.filter('img') ),
        loaded = [],
        proper = [],
        broken = [];

    // Register deferred callbacks
    if ($j.isPlainObject(callback)) {
        $j.each(callback, function (key, value) {
            if (key === 'callback') {
                callback = value;
            } else if (deferred) {
                deferred[key](value);
            }
        });
    }

    function doneLoading() {
        var $jproper = $j(proper),
            $jbroken = $j(broken);

        if ( deferred ) {
            if ( broken.length ) {
                deferred.reject( $jimages, $jproper, $jbroken );
            } else {
                deferred.resolve( $jimages );
            }
        }

        if ( $j.isFunction( callback ) ) {
            callback.call( $jthis, $jimages, $jproper, $jbroken );
        }
    }

    function imgLoaded( img, isBroken ) {
        // don't proceed if BLANK image, or image is already loaded
        if ( img.src === BLANK || $j.inArray( img, loaded ) !== -1 ) {
            return;
        }

        // store element in loaded images array
        loaded.push( img );

        // keep track of broken and properly loaded images
        if ( isBroken ) {
            broken.push( img );
        } else {
            proper.push( img );
        }

        // cache image and its state for future calls
        $j.data( img, 'imagesLoaded', { isBroken: isBroken, src: img.src } );

        // trigger deferred progress method if present
        if ( hasNotify ) {
            deferred.notifyWith( $j(img), [ isBroken, $jimages, $j(proper), $j(broken) ] );
        }

        // call doneLoading and clean listeners if all images are loaded
        if ( $jimages.length === loaded.length ){
            setTimeout( doneLoading );
            $jimages.unbind( '.imagesLoaded' );
        }
    }

    // if no images, trigger immediately
    if ( !$jimages.length ) {
        doneLoading();
    } else {
        $jimages.bind( 'load.imagesLoaded error.imagesLoaded', function( event ){
            // trigger imgLoaded
            imgLoaded( event.target, event.type === 'error' );
        }).each( function( i, el ) {
            var src = el.src;

            // find out if this image has been already checked for status
            // if it was, and src has not changed, call imgLoaded on it
            var cached = $j.data( el, 'imagesLoaded' );
            if ( cached && cached.src === src ) {
                imgLoaded( el, cached.isBroken );
                return;
            }

            // if complete is true and browser supports natural sizes, try
            // to check for image status manually
            if ( el.complete && el.naturalWidth !== undefined ) {
                imgLoaded( el, el.naturalWidth === 0 || el.naturalHeight === 0 );
                return;
            }

            // cached images don't fire load sometimes, so we reset src, but only when
            // dealing with IE, or image is complete (loaded) and failed manual check
            // webkit hack from http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/eee6ab7b2da50e1f
            if ( el.readyState || el.complete ) {
                el.src = BLANK;
                el.src = src;
            }
        });
    }

    return deferred ? deferred.promise( $jthis ) : $jthis;
};

var Grid = (function() {

        // list of items
    var $jgrid = $j( '#og-grid' ),
        // the items
        $jitems = $jgrid.children( 'li' ),
        // current expanded item's index
        current = -1,
        // position (top) of the expanded item
        // used to know if the preview will expand in a different row
        previewPos = -1,
        // extra amount of pixels to scroll the window
        scrollExtra = 0,
        // extra margin when expanded (between preview overlay and the next items)
        marginExpanded = 10,
        $jwindow = $j( window ), winsize,
        $jbody = $j( 'html, body' ),
        // transitionend events
        transEndEventNames = {
            'WebkitTransition' : 'webkitTransitionEnd',
            'MozTransition' : 'transitionend',
            'OTransition' : 'oTransitionEnd',
            'msTransition' : 'MSTransitionEnd',
            'transition' : 'transitionend'
        },
        transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ],
        // support for csstransitions
        support = Modernizr.csstransitions,
        // default settings
        settings = {
            minHeight : 500,
            speed : 350,
            easing : 'ease'
        };

    function init( config ) {

        // the settings..
        settings = $j.extend( true, {}, settings, config );

        // preload all images
        $jgrid.imagesLoaded( function() {

            // save itemÂ´s size and offset
            saveItemInfo( true );
            // get windowÂ´s size
            getWinSize();
            // initialize some events
            initEvents();

        } );

    }

    // saves the itemÂ´s offset top and height (if saveheight is true)
    function saveItemInfo( saveheight ) {
        $jitems.each( function() {
            var $jitem = $j( this );
            $jitem.data( 'offsetTop', $jitem.offset().top );
            if( saveheight ) {
                $jitem.data( 'height', $jitem.height() );
            }
        } );
    }

    function initEvents() {

        // when clicking an item, show the preview with the itemÂ´s info and large image.
        // close the item if already expanded.
        // also close if clicking on the itemÂ´s cross
        $jitems.on( 'click', 'span.og-close', function() {
            hidePreview();
            return false;
        } ).children( 'a' ).on( 'click', function(e) {

            var $jitem = $j( this ).parent();
            // check if item already opened
            current === $jitem.index() ? hidePreview() : showPreview( $jitem );
            return false;

        } );

        // on window resize get the windowÂ´s size again
        // reset some values..
        $jwindow.on( 'debouncedresize', function() {

            scrollExtra = 0;
            previewPos = -1;
            // save itemÂ´s offset
            saveItemInfo();
            getWinSize();
            var preview = $j.data( this, 'preview' );
            if( typeof preview != 'undefined' ) {
                hidePreview();
            }

        } );

    }

    function getWinSize() {
        winsize = { width : $jwindow.width(), height : $jwindow.height() };
    }

    function showPreview( $jitem ) {

        var preview = $j.data( this, 'preview' ),
            // itemÂ´s offset top
            position = $jitem.data( 'offsetTop' );

        scrollExtra = 0;

        // if a preview exists and previewPos is different (different row) from itemÂ´s top then close it
        if( typeof preview != 'undefined' ) {

            // not in the same row
            if( previewPos !== position ) {
                // if position > previewPos then we need to take te current previewÂ´s height in consideration when scrolling the window
                if( position > previewPos ) {
                    scrollExtra = preview.height;
                }
                hidePreview();
            }
            // same row
            else {
                preview.update( $jitem );
                return false;
            }

        }

        // update previewPos
        previewPos = position;
        // initialize new preview for the clicked item
        preview = $j.data( this, 'preview', new Preview( $jitem ) );
        // expand preview overlay
        preview.open();

    }

    function hidePreview() {
        current = -1;
        var preview = $j.data( this, 'preview' );
        preview.close();
        $j.removeData( this, 'preview' );
    }

    // the preview obj / overlay
    function Preview( $jitem ) {
        this.$jitem = $jitem;
        this.expandedIdx = this.$jitem.index();
        this.create();
        this.update();
    }

    Preview.prototype = {
        create : function() {
            // create Preview structure:
            this.$jtitle = $j( '<h3></h3>' );
            this.$jdescription = $j( '<p></p>' );
            this.$jhref = $j( '<a href="#">Go To Contact Page...</a>' );
            this.$jdetails = $j( '<div class="og-details"></div>' ).append( this.$jtitle, this.$jdescription, this.$jhref );
            this.$jloading = $j( '<div class="og-loading"></div>' );
            this.$jfullimage = $j( '<div class="og-fullimg"></div>' ).append( this.$jloading );
            this.$jclosePreview = $j( '<span class="og-close"></span>' );
            this.$jprevious = $j( '<a href="javascript:PreviousImage()"><span class="og-previous"></span></a>' );
            this.$jnext = $j( '<a href="javascript:NextImage()"><span class="og-next"></span></a>' );
            this.$jpreviewInner = $j( '<div class="og-expander-inner"></div>' ).append( this.$jclosePreview, this.$jprevious, this.$jnext, this.$jfullimage, this.$jdetails );
            this.$jpreviewEl = $j( '<div class="og-expander"></div>' ).append( this.$jpreviewInner );
            // append preview element to the item
            this.$jitem.append( this.getEl() );
            // set the transitions for the preview and the item
            if( support ) {
                this.setTransition();
            }
        },
        update : function( $jitem ) {

            if( $jitem ) {
                this.$jitem = $jitem;
            }

            // if already expanded remove class "og-expanded" from current item and add it to new item
            if( current !== -1 ) {
                var $jcurrentItem = $jitems.eq( current );
                $jcurrentItem.removeClass( 'og-expanded' );
                this.$jitem.addClass( 'og-expanded' );
                // position the preview correctly
                this.positionPreview();
            }

            // update current value
            current = this.$jitem.index();

            // update previewÂ´s content
            var $jitemEl = this.$jitem.children( 'a' ),
                eldata = {
                    href : $jitemEl.attr( 'href' ),
                    largesrc : $jitemEl.data( 'largesrc' ),
                    title : $jitemEl.data( 'title' ),
                    description : $jitemEl.data( 'description' )
                };

            this.$jtitle.html( eldata.title );
            this.$jdescription.html( eldata.description );
            this.$jhref.attr( 'href', eldata.href );

            var self = this;

            // remove the current image in the preview
            if( typeof self.$jlargeImg != 'undefined' ) {
                self.$jlargeImg.remove();
            }

            // preload large image and add it to the preview
            // for smaller screens we donÂ´t display the large image (the media query will hide the fullimage wrapper)
            if( self.$jfullimage.is( ':visible' ) ) {
                this.$jloading.show();
                $j( '<img/>' ).load( function() {
                    var $jimg = $j( this );
                    if( $jimg.attr( 'src' ) === self.$jitem.children('a').data( 'largesrc' ) ) {
                        self.$jloading.hide();
                        self.$jfullimage.find( 'img' ).remove();
                        self.$jlargeImg = $jimg.fadeIn( 350 );
                        self.$jfullimage.append( self.$jlargeImg );
                    }
                } ).attr( 'src', eldata.largesrc ); 
            }

        },
        open : function() {

            setTimeout( $j.proxy( function() {  
                // set the height for the preview and the item
                this.setHeights();
                // scroll to position the preview in the right place
                this.positionPreview();
            }, this ), 25 );

        },
        close : function() {

            var self = this,
                onEndFn = function() {
                    if( support ) {
                        $j( this ).off( transEndEventName );
                    }
                    self.$jitem.removeClass( 'og-expanded' );
                    self.$jpreviewEl.remove();
                };

            setTimeout( $j.proxy( function() {

                if( typeof this.$jlargeImg !== 'undefined' ) {
                    this.$jlargeImg.fadeOut( 'fast' );
                }
                this.$jpreviewEl.css( 'height', 0 );
                // the current expanded item (might be different from this.$jitem)
                var $jexpandedItem = $jitems.eq( this.expandedIdx );
                $jexpandedItem.css( 'height', $jexpandedItem.data( 'height' ) ).on( transEndEventName, onEndFn );

                if( !support ) {
                    onEndFn.call();
                }

            }, this ), 25 );

            return false;

        },
        calcHeight : function() {

            var heightPreview = winsize.height - this.$jitem.data( 'height' ) - marginExpanded,
                itemHeight = winsize.height;

            if( heightPreview < settings.minHeight ) {
                heightPreview = settings.minHeight;
                itemHeight = settings.minHeight + this.$jitem.data( 'height' ) + marginExpanded;
            }

            this.height = heightPreview;
            this.itemHeight = itemHeight;

        },
        setHeights : function() {

            var self = this,
                onEndFn = function() {
                    if( support ) {
                        self.$jitem.off( transEndEventName );
                    }
                    self.$jitem.addClass( 'og-expanded' );
                };

            this.calcHeight();
            this.$jpreviewEl.css( 'height', this.height );
            this.$jitem.css( 'height', this.itemHeight ).on( transEndEventName, onEndFn );

            if( !support ) {
                onEndFn.call();
            }

        },
        positionPreview : function() {

            // scroll page
            // case 1 : preview height + item height fits in windowÂ´s height
            // case 2 : preview height + item height does not fit in windowÂ´s height and preview height is smaller than windowÂ´s height
            // case 3 : preview height + item height does not fit in windowÂ´s height and preview height is bigger than windowÂ´s height
            var position = this.$jitem.data( 'offsetTop' ),
                previewOffsetT = this.$jpreviewEl.offset().top - scrollExtra,
                scrollVal = this.height + this.$jitem.data( 'height' ) + marginExpanded <= winsize.height ? position : this.height < winsize.height ? previewOffsetT - ( winsize.height - this.height ) : previewOffsetT;

            $jbody.animate( { scrollTop : scrollVal }, settings.speed );

        },
        setTransition  : function() {
            this.$jpreviewEl.css( 'transition', 'height ' + settings.speed + 'ms ' + settings.easing );
            this.$jitem.css( 'transition', 'height ' + settings.speed + 'ms ' + settings.easing );
        },
        getEl : function() {
            return this.$jpreviewEl;
        }
    }

    return { init : init };

})();
```

Here is the HTML...

```
<ul id="og-grid" class="og-grid">

<!-- The Entrance -->
<li>
    <a href="http://www.thebarnandpinncottage.co.uk/contact" data-largesrc="/images/cottage-images/entrance/image-entrance.jpg" data-title="The Entrance" data-description="The Barn and Pinn Cottage">
        <img src="/images/cottage-images/entrance/image-entrance-thumb.jpg" alt="img01"/>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="http://www.thebarnandpinncottage.co.uk/contact" data-largesrc="/images/cottage-images/entrance/image-entrance-2.jpg" data-title="The Entrance" data-description="The Barn and Pinn Cottage">
        <img src="/images/cottage-images/entrance/image-entrance-2-thumb.jpg" alt="img01"/>
    </a>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="http://www.thebarnandpinncottage.co.uk/contact" data-largesrc="/images/cottage-images/entrance/image-entrance-3.jpg" data-title="The Entrance" data-description="The Barn and Pinn Cottage">
        <img src="/images/cottage-images/entrance/image-entrance-3-thumb.jpg" alt="img01"/>
    </a>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="http://www.thebarnandpinncottage.co.uk/contact" data-largesrc="/images/cottage-images/entrance/image-entrance-4.jpg" data-title="The Entrance" data-description="The Barn and Pinn Cottage">
        <img src="/images/cottage-images/entrance/image-entrance-4-thumb.jpg" alt="img01"/>
    </a>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="http://www.thebarnandpinncottage.co.uk/contact" data-largesrc="/images/cottage-images/entrance/image-entrance-5.jpg" data-title="The Entrance" data-description="The Barn and Pinn Cottage">
        <img src="/images/cottage-images/entrance/image-entrance-5-thumb.jpg" alt="img01" name="VCRImage"/>
    </a>
</li>
```

Here is the CSS...

```
.og-grid {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.og-grid li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 5px 0 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 250px;
}

.og-grid li > a,
.og-grid li > a img {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.og-grid li.og-expanded > a::after {
    top: auto;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-bottom-color: #B3BCC6;
    border-width: 15px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -20px 0 0 -15px;
}

.og-expander {
    position: absolute;
    background: #B3BCC6;
    top: auto;
    left: 0;
    width: 88.888888%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.og-expander-inner {
    padding: 80px 30px;
    height: 100%;
}

.og-close {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.og-close::before,
.og-close::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    height: 1px;
    background: white;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.og-close::after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.og-close:hover::before,
.og-close:hover::after {
    background: #333;
}




.og-previous {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 20px;
    right: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.og-previous::before {
    content: '<<';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    color: white;
}




.og-next {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 20px;
    right: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.og-next::before {
    content: '>>';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    color: white;
}




.og-details {
    padding: 0 40px 0 20px;
}

.og-fullimg {
    text-align: center;
}

.og-fullimg img {
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.og-details h3 {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    color: #4B77B1;
}

.og-details p {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: white;
}

.og-details a {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #4B77B1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 3px solid #4B77B1;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px 0 0;
    outline: none;
}

.og-details a::before {
    content: '\2192';
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.og-details a:hover {
    border-color: white;
    color: white;
}

.og-loading {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #ddd;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #ccc, 15px 30px 1px #ccc, -15px 30px 1px #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
    -webkit-animation: loader 0.5s infinite ease-in-out both;
    -moz-animation: loader 0.5s infinite ease-in-out both;
    animation: loader 0.5s infinite ease-in-out both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes loader {
    0% { background: #ddd; }
    33% { background: #ccc; box-shadow: 0 0 1px #ccc, 15px 30px 1px #ccc, -15px 30px 1px #ddd; }
    66% { background: #ccc; box-shadow: 0 0 1px #ccc, 15px 30px 1px #ddd, -15px 30px 1px #ccc; }
}

@-moz-keyframes loader {
    0% { background: #ddd; }
    33% { background: #ccc; box-shadow: 0 0 1px #ccc, 15px 30px 1px #ccc, -15px 30px 1px #ddd; }
    66% { background: #ccc; box-shadow: 0 0 1px #ccc, 15px 30px 1px #ddd, -15px 30px 1px #ccc; }
}

@keyframes loader {
    0% { background: #ddd; }
    33% { background: #ccc; box-shadow: 0 0 1px #ccc, 15px 30px 1px #ccc, -15px 30px 1px #ddd; }
    66% { background: #ccc; box-shadow: 0 0 1px #ccc, 15px 30px 1px #ddd, -15px 30px 1px #ccc; }
}
```

Comment: Anybody? I have altered it slightly now so that the buttons use a next and previous...

 `$j("a.next").click(function(){
            var $jtoHighlight = $j('.active').next().length > 0 ? $j('.active').next() : $j('.og-grid li').first();
            
        });

        $j("a.prev").click(function(){
            var $jtoHighlight = $j('.active').prev().length > 0 ? $j('.active').prev() : $j('.og-grid li').last();
  
        });`

but it doesn't want to cycle through the list items...

Comment: `this.$jprevious = $j( '<a class="prev" href="#">Prev</a>' );
   this.$jnext = $j( '<a class="next" href="#">Next</a>' );`